# Unable to start my REST service using apache cxf due to the following issue

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, hibernate

I am receiving this error when I am trying to create a REST service call to get my user data from the database and display it as JSON response.

> ```
> SEVERE: A child container failed during start
>     java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/FITConnect]]
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>     Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/FITConnect]]
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
>         ... 6 more
>     Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@7e5b2e5c]
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4842)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4974)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>         ... 6 more
>     Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@2956e3b0]
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
>         at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:708)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>         ... 9 more
>     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
>         at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:113)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
>         ... 12 more
>     Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
>         at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
>         at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:60)
>         at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:717)
>         at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:419)
>         at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
>         at sun.misc.IOUtils.readFully(IOUtils.java:65)
>         at java.util.jar.JarFile.getBytes(JarFile.java:425)
>         at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(JarFile.java:193)
>         at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(JarFile.java:180)
>         at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:111)
>         ... 13 more
>        Jul 18, 2017 2:50:58 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
>        SEVERE: A child container failed during start
>     java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:655)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
>     Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>     Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:947)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>         ... 6 more
>       Jul 18, 2017 2:50:58 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
>        SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
>     org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:655)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
>     Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>         ... 7 more
>     Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>         ... 9 more
>     Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:947)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>         ... 11 more
> ```

This is my web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>FITConnect</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>fit</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>fit</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/service</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/cxf-servlet.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

This is my cxf-servlet.xml used to configure my REST services

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
    xmlns:soap="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/soap" xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
    xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/soap 
    http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/soap.xsd 
    http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd  
    http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.FITConnect.connectivity"></context:component-scan>

    <jaxrs:server id="userRest" address="/">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref bean="userData"/>
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <jaxrs:providers>
            <ref bean="jason"/>
        </jaxrs:providers>
    </jaxrs:server>

    <bean id="userData" class="com.FITConnect.connectivity.UserDataConnectivity"></bean>
    <bean id="jason" class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider"></bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do some changes in your cxf-servlet.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <annotation-driven />

    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <beans:property name="url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/userdata" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="root" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
    <beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>com.FITConnect.Model.User</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
                </beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.FITConnect" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

Also, Delete your existing tomcat server & re-insatll it.

And right click on your project- > go to the Deploymenet assembly ->Add ->Java build path entries -> Maven Dependencies -> OK.